# Need to show $f_k=o(f_{k-1})$ for $k > 1$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Based off the description of an algorithm, I came up with the following worst-case run time

$$f_k(n)=n^{\frac 1 k}+f_{k-1}(n^{\frac{k-1}{k}})$$

$$f_2(n)=2 \sqrt n$$

I need to show that each $f$ becomes asymptotically slower than the previous, i.e.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_k(n)}{f_{k-1}(n)}=0 \text{ for }k=2, 3, ...$$

I noticed after expanding the definition of $f_k$ for a few terms it is $O(n^\frac{1}{k})$ but from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122825/if-f-kn-on-frac1k-then-is-f-kn-of-k-1n) previous question I asked, this was not enough to show the limit exists. At the moment I am stuck trying to prove this.

Comment: One possible way I see to have $f_{k-1}=\omega(n^{\frac{1}{k}})$. I'll think if it's possible to obtain this from recurrent relation, but, may be, from somewhere you already have such condition?

Comment: @zkutch I don't think I have that condition yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised in comment I solve recurrent relation (but ask you double check it):

$$\begin{array}{l}f_k(n)=n^{\frac 1 k}+f_{k-1}(n^{\frac{k-1}{k}})=\\
=n^{\frac 1 k}+ n^{\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k-1}}+f_{k-2}(n^{\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot \frac{k-2}{k-1}}) = 2n^{\frac 1 k}+ f_{k-2}(n^{\frac{k-2}{k}}) =\\
= 2n^{\frac 1 k} +  n^{\frac{k-2}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k-2}}+f_{k-3}(n^{\frac{k-2}{k}\cdot \frac{k-3}{k-2}}) = 3n^{\frac 1 k}+ f_{k-3}(n^{\frac{k-3}{k}}) =\\
=\cdots = mn^{\frac 1 k}+ f_{k-m}(n^{\frac{k-m}{k}}) = \cdots = \lvert \text{ taking }k-m=2\rvert=\\
=(k-2)n^{\frac 1 k}+ f_{2}(n^{\frac{2}{k}}) =kn^{\frac 1 k}\end{array}$$

Now it's obvious to say that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f_k(n)}{f_{k-1}(n)}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{k}{k-1}n^{\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-1}}=0 $$
And, at end,  $f_k(n)=kn^{\frac 1 k}\in \Theta(n^{\frac 1 k})$.

Comment: Madman I think you did it. Looking back at my scribbles I had the arguments all wrong and nothing simplified down.

Comment: Glad to be useful.
May I know which algorithm you are working with? I myself deal with similar issues.

Comment: The algorithm I was looking at is a solution to Algorithm Design (Kleinberg-Tardos) chapter 2 exercise 8b. This article provides the problem text and the link to the pdf at the end of the article provides the description of the algorithm: https://itsiastic.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/algorithms-design-chapter-2-exercise-8/ Neither the article or the pdf really give a proper proof that $f_k(n)=o(f_{k-1}(n))$ so that's what I've been trying to prove.

Answer (score 0):

$f_k(n)
=n^{\frac 1 k}+f_{k-1}(n^{\frac{k-1}{k}})
$

so

$f_k(n^k)
=n+f_{k-1}(n^{k-1})
$.

Letting
$g_k(n)
=f_k(n^k)
$,
$g_k(n)
=n+g_{k-1}(n)
$.

Therefore

$n
=g_k(n)-g_{k-1}(n)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
(m-2)n
&=\sum_{k=3}^mn\\
&=\sum_{k=3}^m(g_k(n)-g_{k-1}(n))\\
&=g_m(n)-g_{2}(n)\\
&=g_m(n)-f_{2}(n^2)\\
&=f_m(n^m)-2n\\
\end{array}
$

so
$f_m(n^m)
=mn
$
or
$f_m(n)
=mn^{1/m}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{f_m(n)}{f_{m-1}(n)}
&=\dfrac{mn^{1/m}}{(m-1)n^{1/(m-1)}}\\
&=\dfrac{m}{m-1}n^{1/m-1/(m-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{m}{m-1}n^{-1/(m(m-1))}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } n \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

for fixed $m$.

Comment: Nice  approach .